# "column does not exist" error with Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-postgresql

The issue appears to be that Npgsql is generating queries with quotes around table and column names.

[Their site documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/table-column-naming.html) mentions this and says to use `EFCore.NamingConventions` to prevent it. Tried this an it doesn't use double quotes around column names but the table name is still double quoted.

When I update `modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Account");` to `modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("account");`

then the double quotes aren't added to the table name anymore.

This feels really hacky and I can't tell if this is the way it's designed to be used or not.

I also tried using collation (shown in code below) but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Error

```
PostgresException: 42703: column a.AccountId does not exist POSITION: 8
```

Database

```
CREATE DATABASE test
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (
    provider = icu,
    locale = 'en-u-ks-primary',
    deterministic = false);

CREATE TABLE Account (
    AccountId integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    Email varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(AccountId));
```

Startup

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
    options.UseLowerCaseNamingConvention();
});
```

OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasCollation("case_insensitive", locale: "en-u-ks-primary", provider: "icu", deterministic: false);
    modelBuilder.UseDefaultColumnCollation("case_insensitive");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("Account");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property("AccountId").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property("Email").IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().Property("Password").IsRequired();
}
```

Model

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

EF Generated Query

```
SELECT a."AccountId", a."Email", a."Password"
FROM a."Account" AS a
WHERE a."Email" = @__ToLower_0
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower-case, so although your databaseSQL script contains `CREATE TABLE Account`, PostgreSQL actually creates a table called `account`; this is PostgreSQL behavior which has nothing to do with EF Core or Npgsql.

Now, on the EF Core side, the CLR type in the model is `Account`, which means that EF expects there to be an `Account` table in the database (not `account`), and surrounds the identifier with quotes to make sure that table is referenced.

To summarize, you can have an `Account` table in your database by creating it via `CREATE TABLE "Account"`; at that point Npgsql's quoted table name will also just work. If you prefer to have lower-case table and column names, you can use EFCore.NamingConventions, or use EF's [bulk configuration in OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#bulk-configuration-in-onmodelcreating).

If you have trouble using EFCore.NamingConventions - which definitely does support lower-casing table names - please open an issue with a code sample on  https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe this is the conclusion I've come up with as well. I guess I just want to make sure this way, of using `UseLowerCaseNamingConvention`, is considered a best practice for achieving case-insensitivity. Coming from the mssql world, I never had to think about case for naming.

Secondarily, I'll open a bug for `UseLowerCaseNamingConvention` not working on table names.